# How to update the state of all the components that share the same class?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

This component is rendered **3 times** in my app.

```
class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userFavorites: []
    };
    this.postFavorite = this.post.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(() => ({
      userFavorites: [{ id: 1, title: "A" }, { id: 2, title: "B" }]
    }));
  }

  post() {
    const obj = { id: 3, title: "C" };
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        userFavorites: [...prevState.userFavorites, obj]
      }),
      () => {
        console.log("AFTER", this.state.userFavorites);
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="button" onClick={this.post} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I call post(), by clicking in the button, the const obj is added in the userFavorites array, merging with the last state.
However it is only added to the 'User' that was clicked and triggered the method post().

Is there any way that I can set the state to all the 3 'User component' on my app, regardless which 'User' triggers the state update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three User components have no knowledge of each other. The shared state should be moved higher up in your component tree.

Below is a mini example which demonstrates the idea. The state is stored in `<Parent>` and passed to each `<Child>` as a prop, along with a callback to add to the state.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [] };
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child name="first" items={this.state.items} add={this.addItem} />
        <Child name="second" items={this.state.items} add={this.addItem} />
        <Child name="third" items={this.state.items} add={this.addItem} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  addItem(item) {
    this.setState({ items: [...this.state.items, item] });
  }
}

function Child(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{props.name}</h3>
      {props.items.map((item, i) => (<div key={i}>{item}</div>))}
      <button onClick={() => props.add(props.name)}>add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks for showing me how to restructure my app in order to achieve this!